# How to determine the full private key(d) of RSA from partially exposed private key, public key, and a plain text-cipher sample?

Tags: rsa, private-key, public-key, modular-arithmetic

To be exact, I search google and couldn't find a solution for 3 days of the problem I am working with. Suppose we have the following data:

```
n = 982596486168164533679068138587450785169755353624059289415533430269902156543301980948452346231423154225707198230814993348325199962226568104628565333075845055110102001513777733822186085910101000971046266247429174698114691926560611342709382763139596083197537103114770536908672391590105944592251557906143423217780862508367523890586749066935355289953519893896713070059149756252671523659055578969907046141090712181640128224480409352033671783234281312447922211039322683639827785375953048086752423328929034805397916713370525669627143719501631537708814980908413840526128966499935897121680247985318025315384432533966964970611
e = 775190819167897631176142663411710999205806087066006443944461953857164338723429823393075674707262963522955617554826880616304988501826679958870898278895792058663197079023581172699525499730454631775015710961671445041794828644629497864625721929989036131201919514003587819878166711621561908547096468667207449797364848789764697856316618498498262452131344181751100590894300580042093702563188859707307216778764928603993071688639278368716846438563956083192844147422032192904730022839373187650224028121273760154048735208506631714555638879414307491200334008651297901472141550888866381591119048114628581521511748434670177461179


partial_d = '-95565380254798212446005426258216042596447135211594111758298376905772484520767625755935413800669744238121798572594037451626724012931827766106358351478966798584005019009384238898207884272864530665811386839587882471633582853938828186423489977-9459392793578-40967083934080473816647050888832190567572370521068219500490996231305841427576808669937665219704595531248268617-5599327544524071502796886348357733378359580273401775-675875610000035372696866273647137752244631988192623168740165719-026394435253643-803573379032337236455340563330139187876245576753031434070779821311882343039420232356-695651945321825753034064267619'
# Where '-' indicated that there is a missing digit. ( 8 digits to be exact)

# 1 sample
plaintext = 174596092887654220987999701151903265828974992233780278786639791235060519357446652195813
cipher = 260977107293095133032309663678665608543832656460900996720257468374788017140947614258160916323627264388927881981964653682851857258414365923694922215834257866016746133459164584766333741801333836289264940490770115570246717428812182110996286021561959704431405293135763955578136678340591578529145822533102991723988404068808248644828190915120779197049355084277184754391753499206475581581888976149876298335630332113681471472312538242128023259706503821080332553580167351146645606566285812912942045955359708168832979660560414335437348485330250971110555548644448362107391181731840051573148892882755700853070019719373415171351
```

How do I get the full private key?

Comment: Don't search google, put pen to paper and start thinking about the problem!

Comment: What do you call e? The public exponent? Why not a common value for e?

Comment: Yes, e is the public exponent. I am doing some experiment on RSA, for that, I am using odd values and try my attacks on that security.

Comment: You're expected to show some effort to solve your problem. Can you at least see the brute-force solution, and comment on why it won't work?

Comment: I have tried the brute-force and took about 8 hours to crack, but I want to know if there is any direct solution of the problem

Comment: There is something that is the square root of the number of steps used to brute force. This attack is called "meet in the middle" or "baby steps / giant steps" depending on the context.